# How can I get the current pose of the turtlebot within a rosjava node?

Tags: ros, pose, coordinates, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a behavior that I am writing as a RosJava node.  I am able to send the robot to goals using the navigation stack, but I need to get the current pose.   Please advise on how this can be done.   I will be running the base C++ navigation stack, and my custom node package is written in rosJava.

Should I subscribe to an /amcl_pose message and cache the most recent one? Or, should I create a TF listener object, similar to this related post?
http://answers.ros.org/question/31815/getting-coordinates-of-turtlebot/

I am referring to the global, /map coordinates.

I have not been able to find anything on this in the rosjava tutorials but it does seem like basic functionality.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35979/how-can-i-get-the-current-pose-of-the-turtlebot-within-a-rosjava-node?/) by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) on ROS Answers with karma: 332 on 2012-06-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an update: I subscribed to the amcl_pose topic from within my own behavior, and cache the latest values for use within my behavior logic.  These values are of course, updated frequently whenever the robot is moving.

There may be a more elegant way of doing this, but this basic approach seems to work fine.

---

Originally posted by [ceverett](https://answers.ros.org/users/1761/ceverett/) with karma: 332 on 2012-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0